# i have integrated firebase crashlytics in my ios project it providing me Objc crashes but i want Cpp crash to catch

Tags: c++, firebase, cocos2d-x, crashlytics

I am working on a Cocos2d-x C++ project and I want to integrate Firebase Crashlytics. I have added Crashlytics as the documentation suggests, and I am receiving Objective-C crashes, but I want to capture C++ crashes. Has anyone worked with this and can offer help?

I am using Firebase version 10.20.0 in a Cocos2d-x iOS project

Comment: Are you [uploading native symbols](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios)?

Answer (score 0):

i use sentry insted crashlytics  and it work for obj c and c++ crashes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).